# How to deny page access directly from URL bar with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a page called signup-landing to which the user is redirected after signing up. The problem is that the user can also at any time type in the name of the page in the URL bar and access it. I need the page to only be accessible when the user is redirected to it. All the methods I've tried just block access to the page completely. Can i achieve this with htaccess?

I don't remember the exact methods i tried, but they were all of this or similar format:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/somepage\.html/?$ directory/somepage.php [NC,L]
```

This would block all access to the page.

Example of what I want to do:

User visits https://www.example.com/signup.php

Through php code, user is redirected to https://www.example.com/signup-landing.php

When the user types in https://www.example.com/signup-landing.php into the URL bar, they should be redirected to https://www.example.com/error/404.html

Comment: Could you please do add your tried htaccess rule file in your question. Also could you please do add sample urls which you want to block too, thank you.

Comment: I edited the question. Don't remember exactly what i tried, but it was various modifications of the example i edited into the question. Added an example of what i need to achieve as well.

Comment: This should rather be solved using sessions. If the user has done their sign-up, set a value in the session, that reflects this fact. In your signup-landing.php check if that session value is set, otherwise respond with a 404.

Comment: This is what i do currently. It's fine for showing a 404 before signup. The problem is once the session value is set, the user can re-visit the landing page after signup at any time. I mostly solved this by including a piece of code on every page, which checks if the page is NOT the landing page AND the session value is set. Then it unsets the session value. Which means once the user leaves the landing page, it can no longer be accessed. The only issue is if you leave the page and use the back button you can't access it. I think i should be able to solve it with javascript's location.replace.